# Host Git Repo on my Mac for Xcode project

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, git

For work all my code must be hosted locally, which rules out using something nice like GitHub.  However, I really want to be able to use XCodes Git functionality.

Is it possible to host the repository locally and have multiple computers push and pull from it? I have a server available but it runs Windows 08 so I'm not real keen to making that work

Comment: Very closely related (almost a dupe): http://stackoverflow.com/q/923130/319403

Comment: The point is I don't want to use github or a server.  If this is not possible, then thats the answer I'm looking for.  Otherwise all suggestions welcome

Comment: running a local server is not IDE specific nor language specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any *nix machine that runs a SSH server can easily host a Git repo with push/pull access.  All someone needs to be able to do is log in and reach the files, and they can clone and pull.  Write access, and they can push.  (You're going to want a bare repo if you want it to accept pushes, though.  Otherwise, things get all kinds of wonky.  Less error-prone would be to provide a way for people request that you pull from their repo, but that requires that each person host a Git repo.  If that's not really an option, then next best would be to let everybody push to a bare repo.)

Git will also work over HTTP, and it's allegedly easy to set up Apache to host a repo.  I've actually had a lot of success with SSH, though.  It seems even easier to set up to me; all the server needs is an sshd, (almost certainly) Git, and appropriate user accounts.

Also note, if you don't need to share, then Git already does everything you need on its own, offline.  All the above stuff only applies if you want other people to be able to pull from (and possibly push to) you.

Answer (score 0):

You can run git or svn right on your machine.  Just set up a local repository.  Note that mac os x has unix under the hood.